# Problems with rendering JSP in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application where I want to use jsp

Here are my dependencies in pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.M2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I try to load JSP page which has

```
<!Doctype html>
```

then the page is partially shown correctly, but not fully - for example

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
```

is displayed on the screen.

When I delete `<!Doctype html>` - then I see only plain html, no view.

I tried to add and delete dependencies and if I add or delete

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

nothing really changes - I still receive either plain html or partially visible jsp.

I have the same problem both when I run it in IntellijIdea and when I run compiled jar

I am stuck here and it feels like I won't ever make it :( I looked at huge amount of tutorials and as many questions on StackOverflow as I could found with no help.

Any advice is very much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
When I use pom.xml from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/pom.xml I get this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [name.valch.SeasonvarApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at name.valch.SeasonvarApplication.main(SeasonvarApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:292) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:168) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you read/followed [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) (especially the mentioned [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/pom.xml) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this properties to `application.properties` (`src/main/resources/`):

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Put your jsps to `/WEB-INF/jsp/`

In your controller return for example "index" you should have index.jsp in this folder `/WEB-INF/jsp/`

Make sure your configuration is like this and @EnableWebMvc is present.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Bean
        public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }

        @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Remove scope provided for these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

the jsp then will render correctly;
[image: jsp rendered correctly]

Comment: Sorry for not posting this to my question - I do have such annotation based configuration in my config  @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }  And my jsp are in /WEB-INF/jsp/ folder

Comment: I see, this class is annotated with @Configuration? is it scanned ? try to add some trace to this method getViewResolver().

Comment: It is marked with @Configuration. Method getViewResolver is entered, but when I try to log resolver.getApplicationContext() I get an error - ApplicationObjectSupport instance [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver@7c71c889] does not run in an ApplicationContext

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try to investigate in this direction now

Comment: Unfortuntely if I try to @Inject ApplicationContext I get no error, method getViewResolver() is called, but jsp page is still rendering not correctly :(

Comment: could you try to add this to your dependencies:        <!-- Provided (for embedded war support) -->
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>`

Comment: I tried to add this dependency, but get the same error as in Update to my question - could you please look at it?

Comment: did you try to add @EnableWebMvc annotation? do you have an online repository?

Comment: Yes, I do have this annotation :( Here is my repo - https://github.com/lenach87/Seasonvar If you could look into it - that'd be great!

Comment: try to remove scope provided for this dependencies:jstl and tomcat, see my update.

Comment: I was able to run you [Seasonvar App](https://github.com/lenach87/Seasonvar) in Spring Tool Suite. All the JSP pages were visible properly, although there are few issues with your persistence.

Comment: @Sanjay Rawat You mean my jsp are displayed properly, not like this http://s018.radikal.ru/i504/1604/9e/60cfdb9b103d.png ?

Comment: @GUISSOUMA Issam - I tried to remove scope provided for this dependencies:jstl and tomcat - but still the same problem :(

Comment: Yes. Your jsp looks proper. No EL tag no sun.java.blahblah, only proper html content. I just downloaded zip from your github, changed DB properties imported the project in STS and Ran application as Java/Spring Boot Program.

Comment: So that's probably some problem with my IntelliJIdea or so, I will look into it. Thank you very much for your support!!

Comment: @ElenaChubukina I tested on IntellijIdea it works when I removed scope provided. Do you confirm it works for you?

Comment: @GUISSOUMAIssam For some reason it doesn't work for me yet, but now I see that the problem is no longer connected with the code. I have Mac, maybe there is some issue with that. I will try to use virtual machine and test it there. Thank you for your support!

Comment: @ElenaChubukina I'm  testing on mac with IntellijIdea15 and running from the IDE, Good luck.

Comment: @GUISSOUMAIssam Just to update - I used virtual box, and everything was fine there from the first time, so I worked there for some time. Than I copied the code (changed in other places) and a miracle - now on my Mac the problem with jsp is gone. I still don't get why - I tried updating Java, rebooted my PC several times, rbooted IntelliJ, cloned the project several times - nothing was helping. And then just copying the folder from virtual machine helped! Thank you again for trying my project - I would probably have spend another weeks thinking the problem is in my code

Answer (score 3):

Did you ever solve your problem? I assume that most of the above guys were getting the project to work using the IDE. Its very different when you run the project as a jar.

Our JSPs are in 
//project//src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
All the pom includes you have is the same as ours.
However I've found that Spring boot 1.4.3 and above stops supporting the embedded JSPs, maybe they want to force us to use thymeleaf;)
I've just reverted to Spring boot 1.4.1 and the JSPs work perfectly from a jar.

Comment: I'm also exploring how to serve JSPs from JAR using SpringBoot(1.5.x). I came across few examples which state that putting JSPs in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/ and providing proper prefix & suffix JSPs can be served. I did the same and was able to make it work from IDE but not from packaged JAR. As you have already mentioned possibly springboot has removed support for serving JSPs from JAR. I was looking for official declaration/announcement for that but couldn't find. Do you have any such link from spring community?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I added JSP support in my SpringBoot application that uses embedded tomcat (packaging => jar):

1) Add required dependencies in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency><!-- Optional, use this only when you need spring security taglibs -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2) Add view prefixes in application properties (yaml example below)

```
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/
      suffix: .jsp
```

3) Configure view resolver:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${spring.mvc.view.prefix}")
private String prefix;

@Value("${spring.mvc.view.suffix}")
private String suffix;

/**
 * Configures view resolver for jsp views.
 */
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix(prefix);
    resolver.setSuffix(suffix);
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}
}
```

4) Create jsp views in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ directory.

You can find full working example on my GitHub: https://github.com/luwojtaszek/springboot-jsp