# SpringBoot app shows Whitelabel Error Page while serving JSP from JAR

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, tomcat, spring-boot

I am exploring how JSPs can be served from JAR file. I'm using SpringBoot 1.5.10.RELEASE

I referred [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1%22this%22) & [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-dynamic.html) examples and was able to create spring boot app which

- includes JSPs at location ***src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/***
- view resolver has prefix as ***/WEB-INF/jsp/*** and suffix as ***.jsp***

Strange thing is when I ran project as springboot app or Java App, I was able to hit the controller and got desired JSP file as response. After that I thought of packaging the app and then running it from JAR.

```
$ mvn package
$ java -jar target/springboot-web-jar-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Spring boot app comes up, when I hit the same URL pattern, control comes in the mapped method but after that...

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Feb 28 21:01:09 IST 2018
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

My problem/question...

- Is there any major difference between the springboot app runs in IDE and when it runs as JARs, which can even cause 404?
- Does spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE support serving JSPs from JAR? (if yes then what I'm missing here, if no then where it is mentioned) - [stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42793468/5155299)

I have tried searching proper solution or answer to my problem but didn't get any. Hence posting the question here please help.

### Note:

- Please don't provide solution for WAR packaging
- I know JSP are not best choice nowadays, I'm just learning
- I'm aware that I can look for alternatives like thymeleaf, freemarker and velocity
- I don't want to downgrade the SpringBoot version
- I've also tried specifying `<scope>` of jasper & JSTL to `provided` and `compile` but no luck

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.atuldwivedi.learn.springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-web-jar-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springboot-web-jar-demo</name>
<description>Learn how to serve JSP from JAR</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Criticisms are welcome, you can down vote the question, but please share your thought why you did so... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For you spring boot recognize their jsps, you debt create a webapp directory in src.main like this:

**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp**

and not like:

**src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp**

Comment: Your answer works for `<packaging>war</packaging>` but not for `<packaging>jar</packaging>`. I have clearly mentioned that I'm doing JAR deployment.

Comment: So try adding to pom.xml: <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: This also doesn't work. Ideally we should not provide `servlet-api` dependency If embeded-tomcat is used.

Comment: I got a maven project spring boot with jsp in [heroku](http://spring-boot-only-crud.herokuapp.com), deployed with jar, wheter you want it, tell me for upload to github

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, I was out of station, please upload your working project on GitHub, I'll fork it and see. Thanks!

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/peterzinho16/spring-boot-jsp) bro, your welcome!

Answer (score 0):

for dispatcherServelet recognize their jsps, you  create a webapp directory in src.main like this:

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp
and also autoconfigure your application in application.properties
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp`

Answer (score -1):

JSPs are not supported when using an executable jar.

Comment: You can't say that. Because he is using a spring framework it might be possible using embedded tomcat. Therefore your answer does not help nor its correct.