# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Demo_SpringMVC/add] in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Just trying to create a simple Spring MVC application using maven,but getting this error(No mapping found for request with URL).Tried every possible solutions provided before for these type of error but not getting the correct result.Any help will be highly appreciate .Thank you in advance.

[image]

I will try to implement the view resolver part later,here simply trying to show one jsp page after clicking on the submit button on the index.jsp page using spring mvc.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.subu</groupId>
<artifactId>Demo_SpringMVC</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Demo_SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.36</version>
 </dependency>
 
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>           
     <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
 <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
 <finalName>Demo_SpringMVC</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>


<form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>subu</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>subu</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

Dispatcher-Servlet named as subu-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
    
    
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.subu.*"></ctx:component-scan>
</beans>
```

The controller class named as AddController.java:

```
package com.subu;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AddController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add()
    {
        return "display.jsp";
    }

}
```

Project directory is like this:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by view resolver part later? Jsp is a view and Spring will need that view resolver in order to identify which view to be displayed. If you do not have a view resolver, you are supposed to get this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with rendering JSP in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714487/problems-with-rendering-jsp-in-spring-boot)

Comment: regarding view resolver part,dispatcher servlet needs to know which view page to display and its format .here i am only providing the view page name and format in controller's method.Don't think that's an issue .

Comment: Even if i don't mention return "display.jsp" and if i mention system.out.println("here"),then also i m getting same error,without getting any text in console

Comment: It's normal because your controller isn't called yet, the request can't access to your controller because of that 404

Comment: how to call the controller here @Onur Basturk?

Comment: You misunderstand my answer. I say that you can't call your controller because you're getting 404. So you can't write anything to console when you can't call the method ok?

Comment: in index.jsp page ,which is the welcome page here i am trying to call the controller's add method as mention in line:

Comment: <form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: @Subhransu please refer below answer

Comment: @Lakshan thanks for the suggestion regarding the jsp package.I got the issue,please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will completely resolve your issue but I see some config issue.

**1*.*  Spring is searching for mapping with URL `/Demo_SpringMVC/add`. Its picking base URL from `pom.xml` `finalName`

Do any 1 of following

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>subu</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Demo_SpringMVC/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

or Map at Controller level like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Demo_SpringMVC")
public class AddController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add()
    {
        return "display.jsp";
    }

}
```

Doing above will at least trigger `add()` method. Verify it by adding a sysout.

**2.** I don't see any View Resolver related configuration. Better to add one, something like below. Also, add JSP's inside `WEB-INF` folder.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your question, error is given below,

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Demo_SpringMVC/add] in
> DispatcherServlet with name 'subu'

reason for this error is, not configured the **InternalResourceViewResolver** in your subu-servlet.xml file. it used to map URI to actual URI. for more info, [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html), [A Guide to the ViewResolver in Spring MVC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial)

modify the subu-servlet.xml file as following,

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
    
    
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.subu.*"></ctx:component-scan>

    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Best Practice**

create a folder named "jsp" under the "WEB-INF" folder and move all `.jsp` files into "jsp" folder. (above answer is based on this tip)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it.I was getting the no mapping error due to this line in dispatcher servlet:

```
 <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.subu.*"></ctx:component-scan>
```

after removing the * from base-package able to get the correct output expected.

```
 <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.subu"></ctx:component-scan>
```

Regarding the view resolver part,i have not implemented it and still getting the correct output from the display.jsp page.i think View resolver is not required here as i am providing the display.jsp page to the controller myself.